# Jenkins/Artifactory - Unable to find method create()

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I am moving some builds from bamboo over into jenkins, using the same gradle build scripting to build an application. With artifactory turned off, the build is successful, but when turned on it fails with:

```
09:22:08.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:22:08.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:22:08.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
09:22:08.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Initialization script '/tmp/init-artifactory2218166479825929225gradle' line: 20
09:22:08.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
09:22:08.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:22:08.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Failed to notify build listener.
09:22:08.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify build listener.
09:22:08.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not find method create() for arguments [artifactoryPublish, class org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.ArtifactoryTask] on task set.
```

The initialization script is being created by the artifactory plugin and looks like:

```
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.ArtifactoryTask

initscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree('/var/lib/jenkins/cache/artifactory-plugin/2.7.2')
    }
}

addListener(new BuildInfoPluginListener())
class BuildInfoPluginListener extends BuildAdapter {

    def void projectsLoaded(Gradle gradle) {
        gradle.startParameter.getProjectProperties().put("build.start", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        Project root = gradle.getRootProject()
        root.logger.debug("Artifactory plugin: projectsEvaluated: ${root.name}")
        if (!"buildSrc".equals(root.name)) {
            root.allprojects {
                apply {
                    apply plugin: ArtifactoryPlugin
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the "archives" configuration to all Artifactory tasks.
        for (Project p : root.getAllprojects()) {
            Task t = p.getTasks().findByName(ArtifactoryTask.BUILD_INFO_TASK_NAME)
            if (t != null) {
                ArtifactoryTask task = (ArtifactoryTask)t
                task.setAddArchivesConfigToTask(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are using gradle 1.5 for this project, the version has been declared in build.gradle.

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply from: 'scripts/wrapper.gradle'
gradleVersion='1.5'

group = 'com.company.build'

task testBuildSingle(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'test/single/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['clean', 'build']
}

task testBuildMulti(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'test/multi/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['clean', 'build']
}

test.dependsOn('testBuildSingle')

task dist(type: Copy) {
    from 'scripts'
    into("$buildDir/scripts")
    eachFile({
        def file = file("scripts/${it.getPath()}")
        println file
        artifacts.add('archives', file)
    })
}

dist.dependsOn('test')
```

Comment: As you can see in `Jenkins Artifactory Plugin` page https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=57182305 . `Artifactory Plugin 2.7.2` requires `Gradle 1.15`. The issue may be caused by version incompatibilty.

Comment: I have the gradle 1.25 plugin and I tried to build w/ different gradle v. in build scripting but it didn't change.

Comment: Can you share `gradle.build` please?

Comment: added to question

Comment: What version of build-info-extractor-gradle are you using?

Comment: The build scripting doesn't appear to list that as a dependency. Is that something required in jenkins but not in bamboo?

Comment: here is the template that generates initialization script https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor-gradle/src/main/resources/initscripttemplate.gradle. This template is part of build-info-extractor-gradle library. `Artifactory plugin 27.2` uses `build-info-extractor-gradle 4.4.5`

Comment: You are using the latest version of  Artifactory plugin and build-info-extractor-gradle but your gradle version is old. Try using latest version gradle 3.1

Comment: You were correct with the gradle version issue. Please add as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Done. I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the latest version of Artifactory plugin and build-info-extractor-gradle but your gradle version is old. Try using latest version gradle 3.1

Answer (score 0):

If your grade script already applies the "com.jfrog.artifactory" plugin, then in the Jenkins job you should set the "Project uses the Artifactory plugin" option, to make sure Jenkins does not add the initialization script. Bamboo has the same check box for Gradle Artifactory tasks.